# Scalar Curvature for a Perturbed Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

If one starts with a pair $(M,g)$ where $M$ is a Riemannian $3$-manifold and $g$ is the metric and further assumes that $g$ is a conformally flat metric with zero scalar curvature, if one then adds a conformally flat perturbation to the metric where the size of the perturbation is small in some suitable norm, will the perturbed metric necessarily have zero or positive scalar curvature, or can it also have negative scalar curvature?

As an example of a metric and such a perturbation, consider a metric which a perturbation of the spatial Schwarzchild metric (which has zero scalar curvature and is conformal to the Euclidean metric)

$g_{ij} = \Bigg( 1 + \frac{M}{2r} \Bigg)^4 \delta_{ij}  + h_{ij} .$

In the case of a conformally flat perturbation, the perturbation does not push the metric away from its conformally flat form so it can be written as

$ g_{ij} = \Bigg( \Bigg( 1 + \frac{M}{2r} \Bigg)^4 + \sigma \Bigg) \delta_{ij},$

where $\sigma$ is a function of the spatial coordinates.

Comment: Can you recall what is a conformally flat perturbation?

Comment: Have you tried to do the computations yourself?

Comment: Notice that metrics with constant sectional curvature are conformally flat. So you can deform a flat metric into a metric with (very smal) constant negative sectional curvature.